# Vue.js Update Array not working using this.$set

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I do a request to a service and fill an object that have multiple arrays inside and it's an array itself.  ex: `this.Jprojs: [{name : 'test', ListItem1 : [], ListItem2 : [] }]`

I put that object in a v-for:

```
<div id="app">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th width="15%">Proj</th>
    <th>Detail</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="proj in Jprojs" :key="proj.name">
    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><strong>{{proj.name}}</strong><br/><a v-on:click="list(proj)"> <font-awesome-icon icon="tasks" /></a></td>
    <td>{{proj.ListItem1.length}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have the method list:

```
list : function(proj){
    axios.get(url).then(
      response => {
        this.$set(proj.ListItem1,0,response.data.value);
        //Vue.set(proj.ListItem1,0,response.data.value);
        this.nextTick;
        console.log(proj)
      },
      error => {
      },
      err => { }
    );
}
```

The console shows the update but the html is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, Actually the property ListItem1 was not in the original Json so vue was not recognizing. what I did was use vue.$set correctly, was using Wrong

both work

```
this.$set(proj,"ListItem1",response.data.value);
Vue.set(proj,"ListItem1",response.data.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to update the `Jprojs` value, instead of `proj`. You coud pass an index instead of the `proj` object.

Get the index with `v-for="(proj, index) in Jprojs"` and pass it as `list(index)`. Then just edit the `Jprojs` array with the given index; `Jprojs[index].ListItem1 = ...`